# Prove that the powerset of a finite set is finite. (correct proof or abuse of definitions?)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, cardinals

Let $ A $ be a finite set, and prove that $ \mathcal{P}\left(A\right) $ is also finite.

Here's what I've done:

Since $ A $ is finite, we can assume that $ |A|=n $   for some natural number $ n\in \mathbb{N} $.

From the assumption above, it follows that there exists a bijection  $ f:\mathbb{N}^{<n}\to A $.

We'll define $ g:\mathcal{P}\left(A\right)\to\left\{ 0,1\right\} ^{\mathbb{N}^{<n}} $ by:

For any $ B\in\mathcal{P}\left(A\right) $

$ g\left(B\right)\left(m\right)=\begin{cases}
0 & f\left(m\right)\notin B\\
1 & f\left(m\right)\in B
\end{cases} $

I'm sure we all agree that $ g $ is a bijection. And therefore $ |\mathcal{P}\left(A\right)|=|\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}^{<n}}| $.

Now, by definition, for any sets $ A,B $ such that $ |A|=\alpha,|B|=\beta $, the cardinality of $ A^B $ defined as $ |A|^{|B|}=\alpha^{\beta} $. In our case, by the definition, $ |\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}^{<n}}|=2^{n} $, because $ |\{0,1\}|=2,|\mathbb{N}^{<n}|=n $.

Thus, we get that $ |\mathcal{P}\left(A\right)|=2^{n}\in\mathbb{N} $. And since $ 2^{n}<\aleph_{0} $, we get that $ \mathcal {P}(A) $ is finite.

This proof is legit? Or maybe I've abused the definitions? I'm asking because this question appeared in my exam (it wasn't written that we have to prove by definition of finite set, so I proved my way).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The approach is correct. I just have to check the part where you proved that the cardinality is $2^n$. Seems OK so far.

Comment: There is something confusing me : Why is $g$ a bijection if it only has values $0$ and $1$ ?

Comment: I am not sure whether you are allowed to argue that the cardinality must be $2^n$ for $n\ge 1$ because every element can be in the powerset or not (This woule be the easiest variant , case $n=0$ is obvious). Or alternatively you can show it by induction.

Comment: @Peter Notice that for any subset B, $g(B)$ is a different binary sequence. g(B) itself isnt bijection ofcourse. But the map from the subset B to its unique binary sequence is bijective. As for the cardinality, It is simply usage of the definition

Comment: Im sorry, I confused $ f $ and $ g $ in the definition of g. Maybe now it will be clear

Comment: You also have not defined $m$. It appears out of nowhere. Same for $f$.

Comment: Read again. f is the bijection from A to its cardinality. m is an natural object. In order to describe sequence we have to tell what it does to any natural element (in the finite domain) . This is m.

Comment: It's a correct proof and it's not an abuse of notation.  My critique would be to question who is the intended audience and the intended purpose of this proof.   Anyone willing to to study set/function mechanics at this mechanical a level would have known long ago that $|P(A)|= 2^{|A|}$.  But this is a good confirmation of how to view things from mechanical view point.  Then again if the reader *can* view things from a mechanical viewpoint I'm not sure it requires this level of gentle persuasion.  Still it's a valid and correct proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some remarks:
Just fyi, $\mathbb{N}^{<n}$ is  frequently used as notation for the set of sequences of natural numbers of length less than $n$ (aka the disjoint union of $\mathbb{N}^{k}$ for $0\leq k<n$) not the set $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$. So readers could be momentarily confused. Also you say "I'm sure we'll all agree that $g$ is a bjection." But this is really the content of the whole proof. The rest about computing the cardinality of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}^{<n}}$ is just window dressing. If I were grading an exam in which a student only wrote that without actually proving it's a bijection, then I would certainly not give full credit.

Now some more specific analysis of your proof. First, it's completely correct (up to showing all the details as I say above). But you can simplify it. For example, there is no reason to invoke the bijection $f$. $A$ is a finite set and so you could just as well define $g$ from $P(A)$ to $\{0,1\}^{A}$ such that $g(B)(x)=1$ iff $x\in B$. Then $\{0,1\}^{A}$ is finite since $\{0,1\}$ and $A$ are finite (as you say already).

Another approach is to use induction to show that if $A$ has size $n$ then $P(A)$ has size $2^n$. That proof has its benefits, but I like your approach for the combinatorial flavour. Your proof uniquely identifies a subset of $A$ with $|A|$ many yes/no questions (for each element $x$ in $A$, is it in the subset?). So $|A|$ questions, each with $2$ answers, hence $2^{|A|}$ many different ways to answer them all.

Comment: Ofcourse in the exam I wrote the whole details rhat you mentioned. I just wanted to know if the idea is correct, because accoeding to my lecturer I just switched the mission to prove that $ P(A) $ is finite, with the mission to prove that the n length binary sequence is finite. Although I wrote the whole details, as you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: Yes fair enough about the exam (just wanted to make sure). So your proof is good.

Comment: "I just switched the mission to prove that P(A) is finite, with the mission to prove that the n length binary sequence is finite."  As long as you explained how they are equivalent, I see nothing wrong with mission switching.